# Akka ActorSystem processing same event twice

Tags: scala, akka

We have a Scala Akka ActorSystem setup that process millions of events per day, historically we rarely find 1 or 2 events that's been processed twice, but recently duplicate events has increased to around 100 on some days.

Our setup simplified as follow:

```
// EventJob runs once every 10 seconds
class EventJob extends Actor {
  val EventListnerPoolOfActors = ActorSystem().actorOf(
    RoundRobinPool(10)
      .props(Props(classOf[EventHandler])),
    "InjectorActorID"
  )

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! ReceivedJobStart()
  }

  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case ReceivedJobStart() =>
      doWork()
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10, self, ReceivedJobStart())
  }

  def doWork(): Future[Unit] = {
    // returns Future[Seq[Event]]
    getUnprocessEvents().map { x =>
      {
        // pass each Event to an EventHandler Actor to process
        for (a <- 0 to x.size) {
          EventListnerPoolOfActors ! x(a)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class EventHandler extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Each Event has a unique ID, in our logs it shows some event has been processed twice (goes to EventHandler.receive) within milliseconds of each other. All actors are local.

AFAIK the default message delivery reliability is at-most-once, what could be the reason that increasing number of messages seem to be delivered more than once, and how to reduce this problem?

Our system is setup to handle duplicates, we just don't know why it seems to be increasing recently, and would like to reduce it.

Comment: What is `getUnprocessEvents()` and what are its asynchronous guarantees? Is `x(a)` a distinct event, or is `x` a distinct event?

Comment: `getUnprocessEvents()` returns `Future[Seq[Event]]`. So, `x` is `Seq[Event]`, and `x(a)` is `Event`. Bad naming I know, that's how we inherited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your system doesn't produce duplicate units of work with the same ID, a possible reason the system sometimes processes a message more than once is because of the way the events are distributed to the `EventHandler` actors; it has nothing to do with Akka's message delivery guarantees.

Consider your `getUnprocessEvents()` method. It returns a `Future[Seq[Event]]` and runs outside of the actor's regular message processing, and there is no insurance that a message `m` was removed from the `Seq` before `getUnprocessEvents()` is called again. Messages are pushed to the workers with no regard for whether they're available for more work. A worker could still be processing a message `m` at the time of the subsequent call to `getUnprocessEvents()`, in which case `m` is again sent to a worker's mailbox. Using a scheduler to call this method periodically--i.e., specifying a time window in an effort to give the worker actors enough time to process their messages--is a flawed approach to coordinating the work.

A better approach is to make the work queue part of the work coordinator actor's state (i.e., make the queue an internal variable in the actor, and mutate the queue via actor messaging) and use the [work pulling pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/howto.html#work-pulling-pattern-to-throttle-and-distribute-work-and-prevent-mailbox-overflow). Also, consider using [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/index.html).

As a side note, `EventJob` creates a new `ActorSystem`:

```
val EventListnerPoolOfActors = ActorSystem().actorOf(...)
```

There should be only one `ActorSystem` per application. Use `context` instead:

```
val EventListnerPoolOfActors = context.actorOf(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response. We understand the time window approach is flawed, it's what we inherited.

However, the duplicate messages are always immediately after one another in the logs within milliseconds, with no other messages in between. If your reason is the problem, wouldn't we expect to see gaps of ~10sec between the duplicates, or at least some other events in between?

Comment: I added logging to find out more information, and changed the ActorSystem creation as proposed. The problem has disappeared, I can only assume the ActorSystem creation was somehow the cause, it was the only functional change apart from additional logging.